# PHP - how to get id of inserted record in CakePhp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Working with the CakePHP 3.0 beta seems like a simple problem, but I've searched through the docs and I can't find anything. After inserting a new record using $this->Model->save(), I'd like to get the auto_increment primary key ID of the newly created record.

With Cake 2.x, I could do:

```
$record_id=$this->ModelName->id;
$record_id=$this->ModelName->getLastInsertID();
```

So what is the alternative in what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it should work fine:

```
$result=$this->ModelName->save($whatever);
$record_id=$result->id;
```

Hope it helps you.